# Show that this power series converges for |x|<2

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series, uniform-convergence

Suppose that $$A:=\sum a_nx^n< \infty $$

for |x|<2.  Let $$|b_n|<n^2|a_n|$$

Show that $$B:=\sum b_n x^n < \infty$$

for |x|<2.

My work:  we know that A converges uniformly inside the interval (-2,2).  Differentiate term-by-term to get

$$A':=\sum na_nx^{n-1}< \infty $$

and we know that A' has the same radius of convergence as A.

**Now, can I multiply A' by powers of x to get other convergent series?**  I think I can but not 100% sure, since the summands will be bigger.

Can I say that, based on the convergence of A', then

$$\sum na_nx^n< \infty $$

for |x|<2? I just simply multiplied A' by one power of x.

If that is valid and does not change the radius of convergence, then I do it once more to get

$$\sum n^2a_nx^{n-1}< \infty $$

implies

$$ \sum n^2a_nx^n< \infty $$

for |x|<2. (First differentiate term-by-term, then multiply by one power of x.)

Finally, using the bound $|b_n|<n^2|a_n|$, I want to use the comparison test and say that since

$$\sum|b_n||x|^n<\sum n^2|a_n||x|^n$$

then somehow $\sum|b_n||x|^n$ converges for |x|<2, which implies that

$\sum b_nx^n$ converges for |x|<2 as was to be shown.

**The problem is that I don't know whether the absolute series $\sum n^2|a_n||x|^n$ converges.**  We know that absolute convergence implies convergence, but I don't think the converse is true.

How can I tweak my solution to get to the right answer?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the [Cauchy-Hadamard Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem).  From the hypotheses, you may conclude that $$\limsup \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\le 0.5$$

Now, what can you say about $$\limsup \sqrt[n]{|b_n|}?$$

Comment: Hi @vadim123, shouldn't it be an equality instead of the weak-inequality?

Comment: What you need is that $n^{1/n} \to 1$. This shows that $n^ka_n$ has the same radius of convergence for any fixed $k > 0$.

Comment: Hi @martycohen, silly question but does this mean that $n^{k/n}$ -> 1?  Thanks...

Comment: Probably does, since it's $(n^{1/n})^k$ -> $1^k$ = 1, right?  Thanks, @martycohen ...

Comment: Yep. I intended for that to be implied for the reason stated. It's a slam dunk.

Comment: That's so cool.  Thanks so much @martycohen!! :-)